# Помогите определить, к какому функциональному стилю принадлежит отрывок текста

Tags: стилистика, стили-речи

Прочитайте приведенный ниже отрывок и определите, к какому функциональному стилю он принадлежит. Докажите принадлежность текста к данному стилю (перечислите основные особенности данного стиля с примерами из текста).

Надо быть храбрым, верным данному слову, сильным, трудолюбивым.
Почему надо? А потому. Вот так принято. Иначе накажут, или выгонят, или будут презирать.
С одной стороны, это хорошо и правильно. Культивировалось поведение, которое позволило выстоять и подняться в борьбе с природой и врагами. То, что способствует выживанию и процветанию общества, то есть большинства людей, и есть истинно, иначе все погибнем. Тут критерием истины выступает практика, всё выясняется через опыт поколений.
С другой стороны, эти практические предписания отбивали у людей необходимость думать и решать самим. Большинство всегда и не хотело (и не могло) думать и решать самостоятельно. Но некоторые умственно непо-седливые всегда хотели докопаться до всех первопричин сами…

Я так понимаю, это публицистический стиль?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По моему мнению, этот отрывок относится к публицистическому стилю.
Общими чертами этого стиля можно назвать:

- эмоциональность и образность речи – для создания необходимой атмосферы;

  оценочность и уверенность – для заинтересованности;

  логика изложения с опорой на неопровержимые факты – для придания речи достоверности и информативности;

  призыв читателей (слушателей) к действию и общедоступность;

  легкое и внятное изложение.

Стилевые черты проявляются на языковых уровнях следующим образом:

- в лексике (употреблении слов) – эмоционально-экспрессивные и разговорные слова, фразеологизмы и устойчивые выражения, диалектные или жаргонные слова – в зависимости от специфики аудитории;

  в морфологии (использование частей речи) – обилие прилагательных, местоимений и наречий, глаголы в настоящем времени;

  синтаксисе (построение определенных типов предложений) – короткие и неполные предложения чередуются с тяжелыми сложноподчиненными, построение предложения – разговорное, простое для восприятия.

Каковы аргументы?

1. Эмоциональность и образность речи имеются. В первом предложении создается возвышенный образ человека, а затем эмоциально объясняется, правильно это или нет.

   Оценочность и уверенность имеется. В третьем и четвертом абзаце оценивается образ, созданный в первом абзаце, и эти оценки подкрепляются уверенными аргументами.

   Логика изложения имеется (опять же «оценки подкрепляются уверенными аргументами»).

   Призыв читателей к действию имеется. Последнее предложение призывает читателя задуматься о том, действительно ли нужно соответствовать образу, описанному в первом предложении.

   Легкое и внятное изложение также имеется.

   Обилие прилагательных, глаголы в настоящем времени.

   Короткие и неполные предложения чередуются с тяжелыми сложно-подчиненными; построение предложения – простое для восприятия.

Comment: Все правильно у вас !